# Firebase currentuser authentication return null value after signed in

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using Firebase authentication method to get detail info of the signed in user (i.e. displayname and photourl).
My code is as follow:

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
```

After succesfully signed in, I signed out to return to the login screen. However, when I tried to sign in again, I got an error referring to the code above:
"**Null operator used on null value.**"

Any sugestion on the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [listen to the auth state changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). Add this method to your Authentication class.

```
Future<void> initializeUser(BuildContext context) async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen(
      (User? user) async {
        if (user == null) {
          print('user is signed out');

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
        
          await fetchUserData(); // handle fetching user data

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const MyHomePage(),
            ),
          );
          print('user has signed in');
          
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi, the error is gone but somehow I can't proceed to the homepage screen, altough I already create the navigator.push

Comment: This method should be called on a init method of your splash screen. Then the function will navigate to the login screen if the user is null or navigate to the home page if the user is not null. From the given information, this is what I can do, If you can provide more of your code I can check what is the issue

Comment: I just invited you to see the problematic codes on Github.